# Problem with reversing Vieta's formulas

Tags: polynomials, contest-math

> Let $\alpha \leqslant \beta \leqslant \gamma$ and $$\alpha+\beta+\gamma = 9$$ $$\alpha\beta+\beta\gamma+\gamma\alpha=26$$ $$\alpha\beta\gamma=24.$$
>   What is $100\alpha+10\beta+\gamma$?

From Vieta's formulas we get

$$\frac{-b}{a}=9$$
$$\frac{c}{a}=26$$
$$\frac{-d}{a}=24$$

so from here we can form the cubic $f(x)=x^3-9x^2+26x-24$. My question is how can I find the roots from this cubic in order to compute the expression they asked or do I even have to find the actual roots?

Comment: If you suspect that there are integer solutions, you might try some small divisors of $24$ such as $\pm1$ and $\pm2$.  Once you have found one, you can factor this out and solve the resulting quadratic which also factors

Comment: It's easy to see numbers are 2,3,4 so expression in question is equal to 234

Comment: How did you see this?

Answer (score 3):

Note that $f(2)=0$, so by the factor theorem, $x-2$ is a factor. You can then factorise $f$ as $(x-2)(x^2-7x+12)=(x-2)(x-3)(x-4)$.